# How to fix this issue Assertion filed

Tags: flutter

How to fix this issue. Someone can help me?

[image]

[image]

My code

```
@override
  void forgetChild(Element child) {
    assert(child == _child);
    _child = null;
    super.forgetChild(child);
  }
```

This is my Element class code.

```
Element? _child;

  bool _debugDoingBuild = false;
  @override
  bool get debugDoingBuild => _debugDoingBuild;

  @override
  void mount(Element? parent, Object? newSlot) {
    super.mount(parent, newSlot);
    assert(_child == null);
    assert(_lifecycleState == _ElementLifecycle.active);
    _firstBuild();
    assert(_child != null);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the code as text as well, but please also [edit] the error to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See the [documentation on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images, as well as [mcve].

Comment: Done. Please check on my question.

Comment: Seriously. This is very long code.